# How to detect & tokens in a custom environment?

Tags: amsmath, environments

I would like to create an environment for displaying context-free grammars.  Specifically, I want to be able to write

```
\begin{syntax*}
  Propositions & A,B & p \mid \lnot A \mid A \land B \mid A \lor B \\
   Contexts & \Gamma & \cdot \mid \Gamma, A
\end{syntax*}
```

to produce the following output.

[image]

By analogy with the `align*` and `aligned` environments of `amsmath`, I would also like to have a `syntaxed` environment so that the construct can be placed inside of other math environments if needed.

To be consistent with the `amsmath` environments, I was thinking to process the above code into:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \text{\scshape propositions} &\quad& A,B &\Coloneqq p \mid \lnot A \mid A \land B \mid A \lor B \\
  \text{\scshape contexts} && \Gamma &\Coloneqq \cdot \mid \Gamma, A
\end{alignat*}
```

How can I detect the `&` tokens and grab each cell of the environment separately?

Here is a sample document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \text{\scshape propositions} &\quad& A,B &\Coloneqq p \mid \lnot A \mid A \land B \mid A \lor B \\
  \text{\scshape contexts} && \Gamma &\Coloneqq \cdot \mid \Gamma, A
\end{alignat*}

\begin{syntax*}
  Propositions & A,B & p \mid \lnot A \mid A \land B \mid A \lor B \\
   Contexts & \Gamma & \cdot \mid \Gamma, A
\end{syntax*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How should the `&\quad&` vs `&&` detection work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,array}

\newenvironment{syntax}
 {%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
  \begin{array}{ @{} >{$\scshape}r<{$} @{\quad} r @{{}\Coloneqq{}} l @{} }
 }
 {\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{syntax}
Propositions & A,B    & p \mid \lnot A \mid A \land B \mid A \lor B \\
    Contexts & \Gamma & \cdot \mid \Gamma, A
\end{syntax}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does setting the `arraystretch` to `1.5` mimic `align*` and friends?  Also, how did you know that `1.5` is the correct parameter?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @HenryDeYoung Not really; `cases` uses 1.2; `align` and friends use `\openup\jot`, which however doesn't act on `array`.

Comment: Also, is there a way to use the `>` and `<` column modifiers with a command that accepts an argument?  I'd like to have this environment automatically lowercase the text column.

Comment: @HenryDeYoung Look for `collcell`

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{syntax*}
{\center
\begin{tabular}{@{}>\scshape r@{\quad}>$r<$@{}>{${}\mathrel{::=}}l<$@{}}}
{\end{tabular}\endcenter}

\begin{document}


\begin{syntax*}
  Propositions & A,B & p \mid \lnot A \mid A \land B \mid A \lor B \\
   Contexts & \Gamma & \cdot \mid \Gamma, A
\end{syntax*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one version of your syntax environment (for the sake of simplicity I omitted the star):

[image: syntax]

This uses `environ` to collect the environment's body which is then split multiple times. By abusing a global set operation the code boils down to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \syntax_format:n #1 { \text{\scshape \tl_lower_case:n { #1 } } }
\cs_new:Npn \syntax_process:n #1
    {
        \begin{alignat*}{2}
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
            {
                \seq_gset_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq { & } { ##1 }
                \syntax_format:n { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 1 } }
                &\quad&
                \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 2 } &\Coloneqq
                \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 3 }\\
            }
        \end{alignat*}
    }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \syntax_process:n { V }
\NewEnviron{syntax}{
    \syntax_process:V \BODY
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \text{\scshape propositions} &\quad& A,B &\Coloneqq p \mid \lnot A \mid A \land B \mid A \lor B \\
  \text{\scshape contexts} && \Gamma &\Coloneqq \cdot \mid \Gamma, A
\end{alignat*}

\begin{syntax}
  Propositions & A,B & p \mid \lnot A \mid A \land B \mid A \lor B \\
   Contexts & \Gamma & \cdot \mid \Gamma, A
\end{syntax}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified egreg's solution slightly.  Most importantly, I restore `\arraystretch` to `1` in the last column, so that `array`s appearing there do not have their leading affected.

```
\RequirePackage { array }
\RequirePackage { collcell }
\RequirePackage { textcase }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__syntax_text:n #1
  { \text { \scshape \MakeTextLowercase {#1} } }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { syntax* } { }
  { \__syntax_star_begin: }
  { \__syntax_star_end: }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__syntax_star_begin:
  {
    \group_begin:
      \use:c { equation* }
        \cs_set:Npn \arraystretch { 1.5 }
        \use:c { array }
          {
            @{}
            >{ \collectcell \__syntax_text:n }
            r
            <{ \endcollectcell }
            @{ \quad }
            r
            @{ {} \Coloneqq {} }
            >{ \renewcommand\arraystretch{1} }
            l
            @{} 
          }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__syntax_star_end:
  {
        \use:c { endarray }
      \use:c { endequation* }
    \group_end:
  }
```

Thanks again to egreg for his help!